# Display div only as per selection from menu list n hide rest of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

i have a Menu in which when user selects from menu list it displays that div and rest are hidden i have a huge menu list is there any function such that  it  displays only that div Can Anyone help please....

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. Also, have you researched it? Have you tried a few things yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
   <li class="one">One</li>
   <li class="two">Two</li>
   <li class="three">Three</li>
</ul>

<div id="one"> Div one </div>
<div id="two"> Div two </div>
<div id="three"> Div three</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    display:none;
}

li {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('div#' + $(this).attr('class')).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: But my menu list comes from database with each unique menu number which will help identify each menu item from the other can this info help u

Comment: I should have guessed that from you not mentioning it at all in your question. My bad. My example should still work, provided you can replace `class="one"` and `id="one"` with `class="<?=$row['unique_menu_number']?>"` etc.

Comment: How do i do use same function for reverse ie   <li id="abc">abc</li>  <div class="abc">abc</div>

Comment: Is there any other way to do it since <li> is differing by id

Comment: Opposite would look like this: `$('div.' + this.id).show().siblings().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a particularly well phrased question, but i'm thinking you want to give all your divs that can be shown a particular class, and give each ond an id:

```
<div class="revealPanel" id="panel1">
<!-- Content -->
</div>

<div class="revealPanel" id="panel2">
<!-- Content -->
</div>

<div class="revealPanel" id="panel3">
<!-- Content -->
</div>
<!-- etc. ... -->
```

You've tagged this query with jquery-ajax so I'm going to assume you know how to include jQuery in your page etc.. Define a javascript function to hide all divs and show a specified one:

```
function ShowPanel(panelId)
{
    jQuery('.revealPanel').hide();

    if (panelId != null)
    {
        jQuery(panelId).show();
    }
}
```

And now just call that function from each of your menu links with the correct id, for instance:

```
<a href="javascript:ShowPanel('panel1');>Show Panel 1</a>
```

Of course I may have misinterpreted your question, and even if I haven't I encourage you to provide more detail in your questions — use code snippets to show how you've designed your menu etc.

Good luck!

Comment: But my menu list comes from database with each unique menu number which will help identify each menu item from the other can this info help u solve my problem